# Issue with loading a large JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to load a large JSON file into a data strucute in javascript. To avoid blocking the browser I have split the data reading loop into chunks. But still I get a blocking browser. Here is my code.

```
function loadTransformation(){  
    $.getJSON('transformation.json', function(data) {
    var NUMBER_OF_RECORDS = data.length;
    var CHUNK = 100;
    var i = 0;
    readData();
    function readData(){
        var cnt = CHUNK;    
        while(i < NUMBER_OF_RECORDS && cnt--){
            // Do some loading stuff here
            i++;
        } // end of while
        if(i < NUMBER_OF_RECORDS) {
            setTimeout(readData(), 1);
        }
    }
    });
}
```

I don't understand what is the problem with my piece of code.

Comment: setTimeout(readData, 1);

Comment: no, actually, all he had wrong was a typo resulting in a useless setTimeout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try:

```
  setTimeout(readData, 1000);
```

[Read about JavaScript window.setTimeout here...](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

You have put call to `readData()` as the first argument to `setTimeout` , which is not what you wanted I guess....

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [Oboe.js](http://oboejs.com/). It is a library which runs under Node.js and web browsers for loading JSON using streaming. Meaning you can start working on the JSON data before it is fully downloaded.

Comment: that is insanely slick. Wish there was something like that for objective-c ;)